# Teen wolf mountain ash myth

Tags: teen-wolf-tv

As seen in many episodes of teen wolf, mountain ash has been used to trap the 'supernatural' inside a circle etc etc. For example, in season 5 (episode 9 or 10?) Liam trapped Scott inside the mountain ash circle. There's one thing that I'm not fully certain about. Why didn't Scott throw a table or a chair to the mountain ash? He could've pushed the table and the mountain ash would've faded away... our would've it?

Question is: could've (for example Scott) in that situation done what I explained there? Or is there something more to the mountain ash that I don't know?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Like a lot of the mystical elements of this show, the details about how mountain ash works are purposely left vague (that way, the writers have freedom to fudge things as needed).

However, the point about the mountain ash is not that it *physically* prevents a werewolf from crossing over it, but rather, there's is a *magical* barrier to werewolves passing over it. We see, near the end of Season 1, Scott's special status allows him to break through a mountain ash barrier with extreme effort, but it creates a visible energy barrier that goes all the way to the ceiling.

The idea seems to be that a werewolf cannot do *anything* that would allow them to break or cross a mountain ash barrier. Any act that the werewolf would take that might disrupt that barrier is *magically* prevented from working. The mountain ash itself would somehow resist any such attempt to break the circle.

There's also another minor bit of supporting evidence in favor of this theory. If you look closely, you'll notice that mountain ash, when laid down by a druid, always seems to fall in a straight line or perfect circle. In other words, the mountain ash seems to "know" it's being used to create a barrier and forms itself up in the appropriate shape to do so. That would imply that whatever magic is driving the mountain ash to work is capable of "fixing" any attempts to break the barrier.

Comment: Correction: It's not the end of Season 1 that Scott has a special status. That's actually at the end of season 3A.